# Bitlocker recovery on Windows after updating Ubuntu

Tags: updates

I could not access my windows laptop after I updating Ubuntu. I did not backup my recovery key before Ubuntu updating as I thought updating would not affect to Windows 10 booting.

I try to recover the key from Microsoft account. I can find the option of getting bit locker recovery key. But to login from my mobile, I needed to update security information.

I got this message, "You can't access this site right now

This site requires a security code to sign in. When your security info updates on 3/5/2020 you will be able to access this site. You can still access sites such as Outlook and Skype that don't require a security code.

On 2/4/2020 you requested that your security info be replaced."

I try to contact to Microsoft agent, but there is no way I can contact to Microsoft to discuss my account.

Now I have 2 options

1) getting a key from my account. But I cannot wait for 1 month.

- Also, I am not sure whether I saved a bitlocker key online. I saved into USB. Some posts I found on the web, with the account-login, Bit locker key is automatically uploaded.

2)Reset my windows, but I will lose some of my documents that have not been backed up yet.

3)Ubuntu updating affects to Windows. May I revert update? or Bios resetting?

Comment: Does "update" mean a normal daily "apt upgrade"? Or did you do a release-upgrade, dist-upgrade, or something else special?

Comment: It seems normal Ubuntu update as apt-get update. I did not do dist-upgrade or apt upgrade. I did not use Terminal. A message appeared on the screen whether I would like to update. and I clicked 'Yes'

Comment: Are you trying to say that you forgot your Bitlocker passphrase? Or that the passphrase no longer works? A normal Ubuntu update has no effect on your Windows install.

Comment: Yes, Bitlocker asks me to enter 48 digit recovery key. I also think that normal Ubuntu update should not affect to windows booting. When I installed Ubuntu first time, windows asks me recovery key, at the time I saved the recovery key to my mobile and delete key again as I am apprehensive that my recovery key could be stolen.